# How to avoid name conflict between object function and global function in Rebol?

Tags: object, namespaces, conflict, rebol

I have an object with a function named `open` that need to call global `open`.

```
obj: make object! [
    open: func [fn] [
        client: open fn ...
    ]
]
```

This obiously fails with stack overflow...

So, how can access global `open` inside object `open` ?
(Please don't tell me "change name" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rebol 3, you can use `lib/open` to refer to the built-in `open` function.

`lib` is an object (which in Rebol-lingo is also sometimes called a "context") which holds all publicly exported functions, including built-in functions. The full name for the `lib` context is `system/contexts/lib` (so you could also use `system/contexts/lib/open` to refer to the `open` built-in), but because that's a mouthful, the convenience shortcut `lib` is provided as well.

Also see [Brian Hawley's answer regarding "user-defined words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713950/rebol-3-where-can-user-defined-namespace-words-be-accessed/17735841#17735841) and [Carl Sassenrath's post on the basic contexts of R3](http://www.rebol.net/r3blogs/0334.html) for more technical detail.

Answer (score 3):

In Rebol 2, you can use `system/words/open`.  If you look at the source of the Rebol 2 protocols, you'll see short cuts defined to these words so that they don't conflict with the same named words in the protocols.