# Retrieving function arguments programmatically in Rebol

Tags: rebol, rebol2

This works at the shell level:

```
>> a: "hello" 
== "hello"
>> get to-lit-word "a"
== "hello"
```

But within a function like this:

```
f: func [ arg1 ] [
    v1: get 'arg1
    ? v1
    v2: get to-lit-word "arg1"
    ? v2
]

>> f "goodbye"
V1 is a string of value: "goodbye"
** Script Error: arg1 has no value
** Where: f
** Near: v2: get to-lit-word "arg1"
```

How do I get the argument value using "get"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I'll mention that when you use **v1** and **v2** in a FUNC like that, you are writing them into the enclosing context.  So they'll act like "global variables".  To suppress that you'd put in your FUNC-spec `func [arg1 /local v1 v2]`.

*(Note: Rebol3 has FUNCTION which scans for locals automatically and builds the underlying FUNC for you.  But FUNCTION meant something else in Rebol2 so that is available as FUNCT.)*

---

Also: when you write `get 'a` you aren't passing a lit-word to get.  Their lit-ness is what keeps them from being looked up, but when the evaluator runs over it...a lit-word is evaluated to become a word:

```
>> type? 'a
== word!
```

If you *really* wanted to pass a lit-word argument to a function, you would have to quote it:

```
>> type? quote 'a
== lit-word!
```

GET is apparently not rejecting you passing it a lit-word!, although I think it would be clearer if it were more narrowly typed.  In any case, I'd write that as `get to-word "a"`.

---

I'm probably a bad person to try and answer your main question.  But I'll point out that even the first pattern doesn't work in Rebol 3:

```
>> a: "hello"
== "hello"

>> get to-word "a"
** Script error: a word is not bound to a context
** Where: get
** Near: get to-word "a"
```

For GET to be able to find a value from a word, it's not enough to just "be a word".  That word has to be bound to some object that acts as the "context"; and binding is a property attached to the word itself.

Rebol 2 acts a little different from Rebol 3 about this.  But if you want a firehose of information, there are some posts on the topic:

[What is the summary of the differences in binding behaviour between Rebol 2 and 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818324/what-is-the-summary-of-the-differences-in-binding-behaviour-between-rebol-2-and)

Often I find that I can get by in cases where I would have said `to-word "some-string"` by instead saying `load "some-string"`.  So in Rebol3:

```
>> a: "hello"
== "hello"

>> get load "a"
== "hello"
```

These function arguments look to be a different story.  You can manually bind your converted word to a context you get by querying something else within that context:

```
f: func [arg1 /local dummy] [
    v2: get bind (to-word "arg1") (bind? 'dummy)
    ? v2
] 

>> f "goodbye"
V2 is a string of value "goodbye"
```

That works in Rebol2, but not Rebol3 unless you use a closure:

```
f: closure [arg1 /local dummy] [
    v2: get bind (to-word "arg1") (bind? 'dummy)
    ? v2
] 

>> f "goodbye"
V2 is a string of value "goodbye"
```

In the category of mysterious statements about Rebol *(like "there are no variables, colon is not an assignment operator")* you can add in *"Rebol actually does not have scoping at all."*

[Is there a overall explanation about definitional scoping in Rebol and Red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964110/is-there-a-overall-explanation-about-definitional-scoping-in-rebol-and-red)

You'll have to ask the experts for more details in chat...

Answer (score 1):

For what it is good for, this can be a little bit shorter

```
>> f: func [ arg1] [
[    get bind to-word "arg1" 'arg1
[    ]
>> f "goodbye"
== "goodbye"
```