# How to use words from a named module inside another?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I'm looking for an example of how to use words exported from a named module inside another module.

From the help of import

```
REFINEMENTS:
/version
ver [tuple!]
    Module must be this version or greater
/check
sum [binary!]
    Match checksum (must be set in header)
/no-share
    Force module to use its own non-shared global namespace
/no-lib
    Don't export to the runtime library (lib)
/no-user
    Don't export to the user context
```

it would suggest that **import/no-lib** doesn't place the imported word in the **lib** context, so **import** by itself should?  But it doesn't.

This works but it seems that import by itself should work.

```
import/no-lib %my-named-module.reb
append lib compose [f: (:my-exported-function))
```

and I can then access the function by using lib/f

Comment: Have you seen [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420942/how-are-words-bound-within-a-rebol-module)?

Comment: @giuliolunati I don't think it works as described. Export doesn't exist as a word.

Answer (score 1):

;in module1

word1: ...

;in module2

mod1: import 'module1

word1: :mod1/word1